# How to change elements in matrices using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, simulation

Starting wish a 7x4 binary matrix I need to change a random bit in each column to simulate error. Have been trying to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

A very straightforward way to do this is to use a for loop.  It might not be the most efficient approach in MATLAB, but it's probably good enough considering your data set is so small.

Iterate through each of the four columns.  On each iteration, randomly chose a number from 1 to 7 to represent the row in that column that you have selected to change.  Finally, flip the bit at that row/column.  The following code does just this.  Assume that "A" is a binary matrix with 7 rows and 4 columns

```
for col=1:4;                  %// Iterate through each column
    row = ceil(7*rand());     %// Randomly chose a number from 1 to 7 to represent row
    A(row,col) = ~A(row,col); %// Flip the bit at the specified row/col
end
```

Comment: `row = randi(7)` would be a simpler version of the 2nd line of the code in this answer

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to create 4 random numbers in one call, and assign in a vectorized fashion:

```
rowNumbers = randi(4,[1 4])
A(rowNumbers,:) = ~A(rowNumbers,:);
```